# Changing icon on every click

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change an icon of a button on every click using jquery. I don't understand why my code below doesn't work. Can someone help?

HTML

```
<li class="navbar-right">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</li>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clicks;
    for (var clicks = 1; clicks++) {
        $('.fa').click(function() {
            if(clicks%2!==0){
                $(".fa").removeClass("fa-bars");
                $(".fa").addClass("fa-times");
            } else{
                $(".fa").removeClass("fa-times");
                $(".fa").addClass("fa-bars");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve

Comment: 1.click bars must chance to times. 2.click times must to chance bars. but someone will click 6++.time. so i want to click event variable as clicks. so clicks odd and even  things must do loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of issues with your code. Firstly you need to give `clicks` a default value of `0` in order to increment it. Secondly, your logic in the `for` loop is invalid, and the loop itself isn't needed. You simply need to increment the `click` value on each occurrence of the event. Your modulo in the `if` statement will then change the classes on the element every second click, which you can simplify by using `toggleClass()`, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var clicks = 0;
  $('.fa').click(function() {
    if (clicks % 2 !== 0) {
      $(".fa").toggleClass("fa-bars fa-times");
    }
    clicks++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<ul>
  <li class="navbar-right">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-2x fa-bars" aria-hidden="true">Icon</i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```